# How to use simple-peer with react-native-webrtc

Tags: react-native, webrtc, p2p, simple-peer

I'm trying to use react-native-webrtc in the constructor for simple peer

```js
import wrtc from 'react-native-webrtc';

const peer = new SimplePeer({initiator: true, wrtc: wrtc});
```

the error I'm getting is

```
ExceptionsManager.js:179 Error: No WebRTC support: Not a supported browser
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to import it like this

```js
import {
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
  MediaStream,
  MediaStreamTrack,
  mediaDevices,
  registerGlobals
} from 'react-native-webrtc';

const peer = new SimplePeer(
{initiator: true, 
 wrtc: { 
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
  MediaStream,
  MediaStreamTrack,
  mediaDevices,
  registerGlobals
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi Walter i am getting an error using your method: this._pc.addTrack is not a function. (In 'this._pc.addTrack(track, stream)', 'this._pc.addTrack' is undefined